# One-time binding of method parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qtip2

I am attempting to one-time bind a parameter within an ng-click method.  The HTML is being generated in the controller as part of a qTip tooltip.  I have tried placing '::' before the method and the parameter, but I still end up with persistent data binding.  This result is that when $scope.data.selectedEvent is updated, these methods no longer reference the original event.  Any help would be most appreciated!

```
        eventRender: function(event,element,view) {

            // bind selected event to scope so it can be referenced in button methods
            $scope.data.selectedEvent = event

            // render qTip with buttons
            element.qtip({
                content: $compile(
                    '<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="Controls">' +
                    '   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="methods.eventConfirm(data.selectedEvent)">Confirm</button>' +
                    '   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"ng-click="methods.eventCancel(data.selectedEvent)">Cancel</button>' +
                    '</div>'
                )($scope),
            })
```

Comment: `ng-click` doesn't create a binding (it doesn't use `$watch` internally) so in that sense there is nothing to one-time bind. A custom directive with a slightly modified clone of the `ng-click` code could probably solve it.